# Using TypeScript 2.3 and TypeScript 2.4 on the same machine with Visual Studio 2015.3

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible to use TS 2.3 and TS 2.4 on the same machine?

I.e. I have on VS 2015.3 project compiling in TS 2.3 but other compiling in latest TypeScript (TS 2.4).

I installed TypeScript 2.4 and that uninstalled TypeScript 2.3. So I'm not able to compile the TS 2.3 project without upgrading it to TS 2.4. The TS 2.3 project is currently only open for critical bugfixes and can not be upgraded to TS 2.4.

Comment: What kind of project have you created with Visual Studio? Can you include more about how each project is specified and built?

Answer (score 1):

You can have installer more than one TS compiler. Install 2.3 then back 2.4 as primary. **Do not do uninstall any.** In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript` you will have (at least) two folders (`2.3` and `2.4`). Make copy of both (`_2.3` and `_2.4`). Then you can switch between them by changing folder names. Visual Studio is using the last installed version (e.g. 2.4). But when folder with name 2.4 contains 2.3 compiler it often works too. Problems are between switching soo much versions (e.g 1.8 and 2.4) because Visual Studio is often using arguments which these prehistoric versions don't know.

This is main concept of changing TypeScript compiler. You can do it handly or you can write .bat files which will make this changes and you can set up this scripts as post-build script of Visual Studio Project. Then Visual Studio will automaticaly "change" TypeScript compiler versions.

Let's write `C:\set-ts-24.bat` file

```
rmdir /S /Q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.4"
xcopy /E /Y "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\_2.4" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.4\"
```

and `C:\set-ts-23.bat`

```
rmdir /S /Q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.4"
xcopy /E /Y "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\_2.3" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.4\"
```

Now set post-build command in Visual Studio Project file. In Solution Explorer right click on Project File (not a Solution) then **Unload Project**.

[image: Unload Project]

When project is unloaded you edit jsproj file. Right click project file again. Then press **Edit yourporjectname.jsproj**

[image: Edit project file]

Xml File will be opened. Add PrropertyGroup element at end of XML document before last closign  tag. In PostBuildEvent set path to `set-ts-24.bat` or `set-ts-23.bat` script.

```
...
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>"C:\set-ts-24.bat"</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then save project file, close project file, right click on project and **Reload project**

[image: Reload Project]